# Can I change the shape of a button on asp.net without css?

Tags: asp.net, button, styles

can I add a feature in the button's code to like change it's shape and make it more round? I don't want to add an image button but just change the shape of the one I already have.

Comment: border-radius is css...  other than that it's up to the browser to render the <button> tag.

Answer (score 0):

you need to use css, just use cssClass="yourClass" in your button and border.radius.

```
<asp:Button ID="yourID" runat="server" Text="Edit" class="btn btn-info yourClass"/>

<style>
.yourClass{
    border-radius: 24px!important;
}
</style>
```